# How to solve invalid default value in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD leave_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT "getdate()";
```

ERROR

```
Invalid default value for 'leave_date'
```

Comment: set leave_date default (like some predefined value or current timestamp) value first in the table

Comment: You need to use _DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP_

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD leave_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE);
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using popsql

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL 8, you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ADD leave_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)
```

(The parentheses are required.)

Setting a non-constant default for a date (as opposed to datetime) column is not possible before 8.0.13.